# ReferenceError is encountered when instantiating a class loaded via jQuery.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

*(Environment: Chromium browser or NWJS running a user interface comprising HTML, CSS and JS with jQuery 1.12.0; exact same behaviour observed in both the browser and NWJS)*

I have a custom HaltError subclass that extends the Javascript Error class with some extra goodies; this is plonked inside a .js file which is loaded by all pages since it's meant to be universally accessible.

I've noticed that, if the file is loaded via ye olde HTML  tags, everything works as expected and I can create and throw my errors without issue in any of the other .js files used by any given page. For example, the following works just fine regardless of where I stick it:

```
var tst = new HaltError("Test error!"); //create error
throw tst.log(); //goodies happen
```

However, if the .js file containing the HaltError class is loaded by way of jQuery's getScript(), the above won't work and I get a ReferenceError instead:

```
var tst = new HaltError("Test error!"); //ReferenceError; HaltError is not defined
```

This is true for any .js file *except* the one containing the HaltError subclass definition, where it works fine. Inside that file, functions can create instances of a HaltError without problems:

```
function throw_HaltError() //call this from another file, and it works fine
{
  var test_error = new HaltError("Test error thrown!"); //works
  throw test_error.log(); //throws without issue
}
```

I wondered if it were a namespace issue, but literally anything else I put in that same file seems to be accessible from other files or the DevTools console; functions, variables, etc can be referenced just fine.

I am aware of the async nature of getScript() and don't believe this to be the problem. For instance, in DevTools, having long since loaded the page and confirmed I can see functions from that .js file in the console, I still cannot create a new instance of the HaltError class (or see HaltError at all in the autocomplete dropdown that appears while you type in the console).

So my question is, is there something different about classes that means they break when loaded via $.getScript()?

I feel like I may be missing something fairly fundamental here!

Comment: As an additional; I replicated this exact same behaviour on another computer in a completely isolated environment (nothing but an empty index.html with <HEAD> and <BODY> tags, jQuery 1.12.4, and a single .js file with a class inside it, which was loaded using $.getScript())